# How can a Spectral Dragon spell be attacked?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Spell: Spectral Dragon ... Dragons of Faerûn, pg. 118

---

As a DM, how would unknowing enemies (meaning, they can't successfully Spellcraft the spell) attack/interact with a Spectral Dragon that is posing a serious threat to them?

---

It can't be attacked or harmed with physical attacks ('can't be attacked' is awkward phrasing). And only has 4 specific spells/magic-items that can destroy it. Yet, oddly, it has an AC and is described as being "not dangerous to the touch". It's like the Spectral Dragon has aspects of quasi-incorporeality, but is even more difficult to destroy.

To me, this spell is bizarrely constructed.  It should've maybe been a dual-school spell such as 'Necromancy / Illusion (Shadow)'. Plus, the text doesn't give a DM a good idea as to how to have enemies interact with it. Hence my question to all of you Rules Experts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this DM were somehow—I dunno—*forced* to have an enemy caster employ the spell *spectral dragon* against the PCs, and none of the PCs made the [Spellcraft](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#spellcraft) skill check to identify the spell as it was cast (DC 21),<sup>1</sup> this DM would plop a Large blob on the battle mat and say something like, "The kooky dude in the pointy hat gestures extravagantly and speaks firmly, 'Ima makun uh dragon!' in Draconic and other syllables you don't recognize. Then in front of you appears a dragon-shaped mass composed of deepest shadow. What do you do?"

Which is probably part of the reason the shadowy form has an Armor Class. While the spell's description says the spell's effect "cannot be attacked" (which, yes: poor phrasing), I must assume the spell's author meant that the spell's effect can't be *affected* by attacks launched at it except for the small handful the spell lists. For example, this DM would allow the fighter to make attacks against the mass—the fighter's arm *not* disobeying the fighter nor his frightened sword *refusing* to enter the shadowy mass because the spell's description says the effect can't be attacked—, but this DM would then describe the fighter's sword blows as having no apparent effect. That is, this DM would let the spell's effect be hit easily (using AC 9)… yet to no avail.

Thus the spell's effect will keep on coming, biting for 1d6 points of Strength ability damage and 1 negative level against one foe per turn as long as the caster concentrates for up to 1 round/level.<sup>2</sup> Sharp players should soon realize that the mass has no reach, makes no attacks of opportunity, has no threatened area and, because of how [range](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#range) works, doesn't move farther than 25 ft. +5 ft./2 caster levels from the caster despite the caster being able to take a move action to [redirect the spell's effect](http://dndsrd.net/actionsInCombat.html#direct-or-redirect-a-spell) to 60 ft. with the spell's range.<sup>3</sup> I suspect especially smart players whose PCs have enough room to do so will simply tell allies to back up 50 ft. or so then have allies who can launch ranged attacks at the caster of the *spectral dragon* spell until the caster dies.

By the way, I suspect the real reason the spell's effect has an AC is so that it can be targeted by the 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*disintegrate*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#disintegrate) [trans] (*PH* 222) and the [*rod of cancellation*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsPRR.html#rod-of-cancellation) (*DMG* 234) (11,000 gp; 5 lbs.), both of which require their users to make a touch attack to hit the mass.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Such a failure *is* possible, I guess. A Wiz11 *can be* an overpowering encounter for some level 6 PCs (5% of them are; see *DMG* 49) *and* the two PCs with maximum ranks in the Spellcraft skill could both not get a 12 or higher on the Spellcraft check. Mean encounter, though. (Also note that this DM urges every PC to have at least 1 rank in the skill Spellcraft—it's a survival thing.)
<sup>**2**</sup> Honestly, this isn't a very impressive effect for a level 11 caster's standard action. Such a caster had the 4th-level spell [*enervation*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#enervation) [necro] (*PH* 224) *four level ago*, for example, and that spell only requires a touch attack rather than the *spectral dragon* spell effect's normal attack roll.
<sup>**3**</sup> Another DM may give the spell's effect a reach of 5 ft. even though the spell itself doesn't instead of forcing the mass to move into a creature's space to make its bite attack. However, as printed, the spell's effect has no reach.

Comment: Excellent insight, H.I.C.C. With footnotes, no less.  :-)  Good point on what sharp players would notice about the Spectral Dragon's operating quirks. Also, while it's a true suboptimal spell choice at L11, it could be useful, action-economy-wise,  if Concentration control is transferred to your familiar via the Familiar Concentration feat (LEoF p. 8).

Comment: @Crai [The typical familiar never has Int 16](http://dndsrd.net/wizard.html#familiar-basics) hence can't take over control of the spell. If a caster's willing take the feat Familiar Concentration and the feat Improved Familiar for an Int 16 familiar, then I guess the spell *might* be okay… or, instead, the caster could've spent a standard action casting an empowered *enervation* spell and his improved familiar could've used a *wand of enervation*. The *spectral dragon* handoff combo'd be *really* low on my list, though—like for showing off: a "My familiar can kick your ass!" kind of sitch.

Comment: Aye. Agreed. Theorycrafting, I was thinking a wizard with the Dragon Familiar feat (Bronze Wyrmling) via Draconomicon [p. 104] and boosting him with +2 Headband of Intellect. Primarily for transferring Telekinesis. But, a Spectral Dragon being controlled by a real dragon (as a secondary schtick) kinda captures my fancy. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Although the dragon created by the spell can't be attacked it is not like a corporeal dragon, it is instead a being made of shadow that is shaped like a dragon.

The spell text reads:

"You create a Large dragon-shaped mass of shadows that attacks under your control."

It cannot be harmed by normal means but it's caster can, and as a DM or as a player you should search the controler of the spell so thats how you deal with it.

Comment: Thanks, Victor.  Yeah, that specific quote implies that that an enemy viewer is highly likely to be skeptical that it's a real dragon-like creature.

Answer (score 1):

There are answers to your sub-questions step-by-step:

---

Most enemies still know that you just cast a spell, no matter if spellcraft is out of use for them or if they failed it. They know it's just a spell effect and act accordingly. Most likely, accordingly to their Int and overall tactics. There is no single answer to this part of the question: some monsters would at least try to kill it, others will attack you directly, at last it's no surprise enemies may try to escape. It all depends on power level and prefered tactics of each single monster or pack of them.

---

First of all, for most of your mechanical sub-questions, the spell is obvious tracing from Spiritual Weapon (paragraphs 3 and 4). Dragon just can't be harmed by damage, nothing new here. It has touch AC listed because some ways to destroy it require a touch attack.
Probably, one may also affect it with some other spells or abilities even if they wouldn't destroy it. Those things may also require hitting the dragon.
As for "safe to the touch", this part means, that dragon deals damage only on a successful hit. Hitting it with your arms/claws, walking by or through it wont hurt you. It is also a common thing in D&D 3.5: others touchig you is not the same as you touching others.

Finaly, it wery well might've apear dual-school spell or maybe illusion (shadow) one. I don't think it would significantly change the outcome, maybe just make the whole thing a bit more consistent. Still it was up to designers and they did it as is.

Comment: Thank you very much, A.I. Good catch on the Spiritual Weapon corollary.